# How to enable Developer Resources Section in appstoreconnect (Users and Access)?

Tags: app-store-connect

I have stuck in one scenario, I have provided admin rights to one user accounts but they can not access profile & certificate section in developer apple site. I have google it but nothing find for solution. In Users and Access Section when i add user account (email address) at that time Developer Resources section is disable so i need to help how to enable that section. 
In My account two-factor authentication is enabled.
[image: Developer resources default disabled]

All the roles are enabled 
[image: All the permission is given]

Previously i have follow below steps for give access to user before flow changes by apple.

```
First :  (Apple Developer)

Sign in to developer.apple.com/account, and click People.
Click Invite People.
Enter the email address of the person you want to invite as an Admin in the top section.
Click Invite.


Second (iTunes Connect)
https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/ 
Goto -> User & Access
People Tab -> Add New
```

I have read out this link but not getting success. 
Link: [developer-account learn more](https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/dev4c557019f)

Comment: Can I able to create developer certificates in the individual enrollment

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If enrolled as an individual, you cannot provide access to `Profiles & Certificates` over at https://developer.apple.com/account

Only organization accounts allow this functionality. (https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/ bottom option "Enrolling as an Organization")

If you have a company/organization account, over at https://appstoreconnect.apple.com > Users & Access > People you will find a section "Developer Resources". Check it to give the person (full) access to certs, identifiers and profiles.

[image]

Comment: In Permissions in App Store Connect Section apple write note :
"Note: If you’re enrolled as an individual and add users in App Store Connect, users receive access only to your content in App Store Connect and are not considered part of your team in the Apple Developer Program.
"
Link: https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/


Thank you @Max for sharing information

Comment: Yes that was always the case. Individuals can only invite people to App Store Connect, but not to Apple Developer Center. For that you need a company account. The "unification" of both teams only happened for company accounts.

Comment: @Max I have an apple account with individual enrollment. Can I able to switch to organisaion enrollment with the same package. I already paid for individual enrollment. Or can I claim that paid amount. Or can you suggest any solution on how to create certificates with in this.

Comment: @sejn You can contact Apple Developer support and "upgrade"/transform your existing account into a company/organisation one. You will need a valid DUNS for that legal entity though.

Comment: @Max Thanks so I can't able to create certificate with individual enrollment and need to switch to organisational enrollment

Comment: @sejn You can create 1x distribution certificate with your own Apple ID. Users you invite to your account, can only have access to App Store Connect and cannot do any functions on the Apple Developer Center as they do not have access.